# How Sessions works in a load balancing environment?

Tags: session, load-balancing

I have a web site which runs on a single server. Now the number of users are becoming high. So we are planning to introduce a load balancing server in few days.. What all thing i need to keep in mind for implementing the load blacking server? How the session will work in such an environment?
NB:The application is done in Asp.net / MS SQL

Answer (score 1):

If the load balancer supports sticky sessions you could use them to ensure that a users requests are serviced by the same server. This is the best performing option.

Other approaches are,

1. Asp.net session service on a common server
2. Asp.net session state in SQL server
3. Using app fabric

Answer (score 1):

Load Balancers have Persistent Session feature. When configuring load blancer you can yourself or ask support to enable this feature so users once served by serverA will be served by serverA throughout the session.

This should give you more insight about load balancers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29#Persistence